How to solve the issue of "AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute" with playing video in SwiftUI?
This is my test code for playing video in SwiftUI, the video start playing in first time, but when I update the url for other video it shows like multiple (10-20 times) line of:

"AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute"

in Xcode console. From what I see I did not made wrong code for this issue, how ever I also could not find an answer in internet for this logs. The videos are playing after click but each time after updating the url this logs comes out in Xcode.
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var AVPlayerURL: URL? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            if let AVPlayerURL {
                VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(url: AVPlayerURL))
            }

            HStack {
                
                Button("Play video 1") {
                    AVPlayerURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "myVideo1", withExtension: "mp4")
                }
                
                Button("Play video 2") {
                    AVPlayerURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "myVideo2", withExtension: "mp4")
                }
                
                Button("Play video 3") {
                    AVPlayerURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "myVideo3", withExtension: "mp4")
                }
                
            }

        }
        .padding()
        
    }
}


Don’t use singletons use the Environment/EnvironmentObject, singletons are not synched with SwiftUI and don’t match up with body reloading

Before this codes i tried that with Environment and onChange, but Xcode keep saying that onChange is Deprecated! So I came up with current codes.

Just use the new onChange or task(id:) this code won't work

"...Xcode keep saying that onChange is Deprecated", all you need to do then is to read the documentation

@JoakimDanielson: This question is not about onChange, how ever all you need to do is reading the question and maybe answer it. ps: onChange is Deprecated, how ever all you need to do is trying use it by apple documentation which you know and you will see it is Deprecated.

And if you actually read the documentation you see there’s links to the new onChange functions that replaces the deprecated ones.

And if you actually read my last comment you would see the question is not about onChange

I just reacted to your incorrect claim that onChange is deprecated, this is the comment section where we can post comments about the question or respond to already posted comments.

Here I find a way for solving the issue of Xcode logs.
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

@main
struct AVPlayer_TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView().environmentObject(AVPlayerModel.shared)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var myAVPlayerModel: AVPlayerModel
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Group {
                
                if let unwrappedPlayer: AVPlayer = myAVPlayerModel.player {
                    VideoPlayer(player: unwrappedPlayer)
                }
                else {
                    Color.black
                }
                
            }
            .cornerRadius(5.0)
            
            ButtonView()
            
        }
        .padding()
        
    }
    
}

struct ButtonView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var myAVPlayerModel: AVPlayerModel
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            
            Button("Play video 1") {
                myAVPlayerModel.AVPlayerURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "myVideo1", withExtension: "mp4")
            }
            
            Button("Play video 2") {
                myAVPlayerModel.AVPlayerURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "myVideo2", withExtension: "mp4")
            }
            
            Button("Play video 3") {
                myAVPlayerModel.AVPlayerURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "myVideo3", withExtension: "mp4")
            }
            
        }
        
    }
}

class AVPlayerModel: ObservableObject {
    
    static let shared: AVPlayerModel = AVPlayerModel()
    
    @Published var AVPlayerURL: URL? = nil {
        
        didSet(oldValue) {
            
            if let unwrappedAVPlayerURL: URL = self.AVPlayerURL {
                
                if let unwrappedOldValue: URL = oldValue {
                    
                    if (unwrappedAVPlayerURL != unwrappedOldValue) {
                        self.player?.pause()
                        self.player = nil
                    }
                    else {
                        
                        let seekToZero = CMTime(seconds: 0, preferredTimescale: 60000)
                        self.player?.seek(to: seekToZero, toleranceBefore: .zero, toleranceAfter: .zero)

                        return
                    }
                    
                }
                else {
                    self.player?.pause()
                    self.player = nil
                }
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if let unwrappedAVPlayerURL: URL = self.AVPlayerURL {
                        self.player = AVPlayer(url: unwrappedAVPlayerURL)
                        self.player?.play()
                    }
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    @Published var player: AVPlayer? = nil
    
}


The problem seems to be that we need to let the existing VideoPlayer view disappear (or update itself, not sure how to best word this) before creating a new view for the next video. Given the SwiftUI lifecycle I decided to split the change into two changes so that the view got a chance to update itself before playing the new video.
So first let's use two State properties
@State private var videoName: String?
@State private var player: AVPlayer?

and then use two onChange for each of them creating a chain reaction
.onChange(of: videoName) { _, newName in
    player?.pause()
    if let newName = newName {
        player = AVPlayer(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: newName, withExtension: "mp4")!)
    }
}
.onChange(of: player) { _, newPlayer in
    if let newPlayer = newPlayer {
        newPlayer.play()
    }
}

So the first onChange will create a new AVPlayer and the second will play the new video but a cycle has passed between them so the view is now in a correct state and won't print any warnings.
Of course the buttons will need tp be updated to set the video name
Button("Play video 1") {
    videoName = "video1"
}
// and so on...


It does not solve the issue, did you tried to run your codes? I consider this answer unprofessional and obstinate! Also in previous commend under question, how the OP should ask you about the issue of  "AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute" and NOT use case of onChange? I even did not use onChange in question. Are you trying to show that you know the use case of onChange? well this is not the right place and question sir. The OP asked about solving the issue of xcode logs, also your current answer does not solve the issue. I ask you be a professional. thanks

Of course I ran the code, I used your code first to make sure I could reproduce the issue and then I experimented some, read some and came to this solution. Not mentioned in my answer below but this is written and tested for a macOS app since I assumed from some of your previous questions that this is your target. When you say it didn't work, did you apply the solution to the code you posted in your question or some other code because I can only post solutions to the code that is given in the question.

Please stop resistance about the facts! Your code does not solve the issue in Xcode logs, we both also other users know why post this answer. I am sure it will not change any thing in your mind speaking about facts and the issue of the question, and you will still resistance and obstinate. I solved the issue by myself I will answer the question.

I'm looking forward to seeing your solution but I recent your accusations and strange claims and I wonder why you aren't answering my question about how you tested my solution.
